# How to configure testng testsuite in jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, testng

I am using `Maven` project and I have different `TestNG` suite file. Now I ve to configure `Jenkins` and POM.xml file where I've to call my individual testsuite from `Jenkins`. Please help me out how to configure my project.

I've configured my pom.xml file as below

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.*</include>
            </includes>
            <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>${project.basedir}/src/test/java/com/cisco/citeis/suites/${x‌​mlfile}</suiteXmlFile>
            </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

In Jenkins I add command `clean test -Dsuite= AppFlow.xml`

Comment: Three things : 1. `testng.xml` 2. `TestRunner` and before all that 3. `show us what you've done.`

Comment: I've configured my pom.xml file as <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <includes>
      <include>**/*.*</include>
     </includes>

     <suiteXmlFiles>
      <suiteXmlFile>${project.basedir}/src/test/java/com/cisco/citeis/suites/${xmlfile}</suiteXmlFile>
     </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>

Comment: I dn't know how to call parameter inJenkins

Comment: in Jenkins I add command clean test -Dsuite= AppFlow.xml

Comment: If you are marking your variable as ${xmlfile}, then you should be passing -Dxmlfile instead of -Dsuite.  Rest all is fine.

Comment: Thanks niharika_neo. It is working fine

Answer (score 0):

In the POM file add

```
<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <suiteFile></suiteFile>
</properties>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${suiteFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

and in jenkins add the following command

clean test -DsuiteFile=\AppFlow.xml